# Find recently modified files and manipulate output

Tags: python, linux, unix, find, tail

My intention:

1. Find files that have been modified in the last 2 days.
2. Get last 500 lines (since application log files are big) of each of those files.
3. Put each tail output into a different file (since I need to download it to a remote machine).

I then download these files from the remote machine to my local machine using Python Fabric.

Am able to do 1 and 2 using :`find /opt/tomcat/logs -mtime -2 -exec sudo tail -500 '{}' \;`

Am able to do 2 and 3 using:
 `'sudo tail -500 ' + filename + ' | sudo tee ' + logfilename + '_tail'`

How can I get 1, 2 and 3 accomplished in 1 command itself?

I need it in 1 command as i am using Python sshcon.exec_command() to do this on a remote machine.

Comment: Write a shell script and call it from Python.

Comment: i need to do above operation on multiple servers...any easier way than uploading the shell script to each server?

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script to achieve your desired end results.

Then run it using subprocess module.

Make sure, you are piping the shell script while `subprocess.call()`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sshpass -p pass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
               user@remote_server_ip  'bash -s' < your_script.sh ",shell=True)
```

Let's say, you have a script test_script.sh and you want to run it on three server (1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.6). Now the approach should be:

```
import subprocess
servers = [1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.6]
for server in servers:
    subprocess.call("sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
           username@{0} 'bash -s' < test_script.sh ".format(server),shell=True)
```

This will be more than enough to achieve your goal provided you have `sshpass` installed.

Comment: i need to do this kind of operation on multiple servers...any easier way than uploading the shell script to each server?

Comment: You don't need to upload the shell script to each server in my above approach. You can see the updated answer.

Comment: The argument to `call` is a single command; you'd do well to tokenize it into a list and lose the icky `shell=True`.